# Show $\mathbb{D}^2 \setminus\{(0,0)\}$ is homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{S}^1$.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Show that the disc $\mathbb{D}^2 = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x^2 + y^2 \le 1 \}$ with the origin $(0,0)$ removed is homotopy equivalent to the circle $\mathbb{S}^1.$

I understand the general method, but am just unsure with the specifics in this example. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: At time $t\in[0,1]$ push each point of the punctured disk radially $t$ fraction of the way to the boundary. (To get the set difference operation use \setminus.

Comment: But how can I define functions $f,g: X \to Y$ and $H: X \times [0,1] \to Y$ such that $H(x,0)=f(x)$ and $H(x,1)=g(x) \forall x \in X$?

Comment: To see how the (very thorough) answer fits in with the geometry, draw the picture!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming that your definition of $S^1$ is the boundary of $D^2$, i.e.
$$S^1 = \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 : x^2 + y^2 = 1\}.$$

Let $f: S^1 \rightarrow D^2$ be defined by inclusion, i.e. $f(x,y) = (x,y)$, and $g: D^2  \setminus \{(0,0)\} \rightarrow S^1$ be defined by
$$g(x,y) = \frac{(x,y)}{||(x,y)||}.$$
Geometrically, this map takes a point in $D^2  \setminus \{(0,0)\}$ and "pushes it" outward to the boundary of the circle.

Obviously $g\circ f$ is the identity on $S^1$. We still need to show a homotopy between $f \circ g$ and $id_{D^2}$. Let $F: D^2 \times I \rightarrow D^2$ be defined by
$$F((x,y),t) = t\frac{(x,y)}{||(x,y)||} + (1-t)(x,y).$$

Clearly $F((x,y),0) = id_{D^2}$ and $F((x,y),1) = (f\circ g)(x,y)$, as desired.

Remark: As Chickenmancer points out in the comments, the homotopy I wrote down is an instance of the "straight-line homotopy", which is a generally useful tool for writing down homotopies without thinking too hard.

EDIT: Reading your comment, I think you have a misunderstanding about the definition of homotopy equivalence. Two spaces $X, Y$ are said to be homotopy equivalent if you can find maps $f: X \rightarrow Y$ and $g: Y \rightarrow X$ such that $f \circ g \simeq id_Y$ and $g \circ f \simeq id_X$. Your maps should not both be from $X$ to $Y$.

Comment: Straight line homotopy ftw.

Comment: I haven't seen this straight line homotopy before. Does look to be more simple. Would there be other ways of doing it though, because it's not quite what I'm used to. I appreciate the long explanation though! Is this the way you'd advise I go about it in the future. If I did a question involving $\mathbb{S}^2$ for instance?

Comment: What is the way you are used to doing it? The straight-line homotopy is sort of the first thing you would try if you were trying to build a homotopy from scratch. I think that most of the time, you're using the straight-line homotopy without even realizing!

Comment: Maybe showing the general form of the straight-line homotopy is helpful. Suppose you want to find a homotopy between maps $f$ and $g$. Then try $tg + (1-t)f$ -- clearly at $t = 0$ you have $f$ and at $t = 1$ you have $g$! You do have to make sure that at all $t$ your homotopy is well-defined; this amounts to showing that the straight line between $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ is in your codomain.

Comment: Yes, I think possibly that that's more what I've seen before. That makes a little more sense to me anyway, but I can see the logical way that you've gone about it with the straight line homotopy. I'll try doing both things and hopefully that should work. I think you might be right that I've used it without actually realising.